# Como buscar imagens no Google com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, google-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma página web onde era de interesse do projeto exibir algumas imagens do [Google](http://www.google.com.br), onde estas seriam exibidas a partir de algum nome significativo.

Estava lendo algo relacionado e vi que o [Google Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/?hl=pt-br) foi descontinuado. Existe algo parecido ou ainda é possível usar essa API para a minha finalidade?

Comment: Posso postar com jQuery?

Comment: Pode! @RonnyAmarante

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Este código está uma porcaria, porém, funciona. Fiz rapidinho porquê ví que ninguém respondeu sua questão.. Acerca da API do Google, você fará algumas solicitações e terá alguns erros, essa API é paga, a API que você mandou acima está obsoleta, agora é a Custom Search que está em uso. Então se após algumas tentativas você não conseguir pode ser devido a essa cobrança.

Código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    //Usando jQuery
    a = $.getJSON( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=2.0&hl=pt-br&cr=countryBR&q=carros")
  .done(function( json ) {
    b = jQuery.parseJSON(a.responseText)
    for ( var i = 0; i < b.responseData.results.length; i++ ) {

        document.write("<img src='"+b.responseData.results[i].unescapedUrl+"' />");
}
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    document.write("Erro ao capturar JSON");
});

</script>
    </body> 

</html>
```

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: É normal o seu navegador bloquear as tentativas de getJSON devido ao CORS. Existem formas de burlar, então recomendo que você utilize já no servidor de produção para efetuar os seus testes. 
http://superuser.com/questions/384871/overriding-access-control-allow-origin-restriction-in-google-chrome

Comment: Essa tecnica acima é na verdade um Web scraping. Para fins de estudo, não ha nenhum problema de você pratica-la, porém, se você está fazendo um produto (site, web app, etc) que implementa essa tecnica em qualquer parte da sua aplicação, será considerado como ilegal e talvez você (ou seu cliente) sejam processados juridicamente por isso, então é bom evitar essa dor de cabeça. Aqui nos Estados Unidos, alguns sites não consideram essa pratica como ilegal (precisa ler nos termos), na ausência dessa informação, ela será considerada ilegal.

Comment: Amigo @JanCássio, na verdade isso não é ilegal. O acesso é através de um JSON disponibilizado pelo Google, no qual o Google permite acessos públicos, porém, para grandes quantidades de acesso oferece o serviço com cobrança. O que é disponibilizado via API não é ilegal, existe uma enorme diferença. O navegador bloqueia o CORS devido a questões de segurança, apenas isso.

Comment: Acho que viajei nesse comentário, a sua implementação esta ok. O problema com CORS que você se refere é no response do serviço ou na requisição de um resource (imagem) fornecida pelo serviço?

Comment: Ele bloqueia o recebimento do JSON externo

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão é você procurar um serviço especifico para busca de imagens e o melhor que eu conheço é o Flickr. Além da API ser excelente, há uma enorme base de imagens disponivel.

[Este serviço](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) por exemplo, é a busca padrão de imagem disponivel no próprio site.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Isto não responde a pergunta. Seria melhor deixar esta informação como um comentário ao invés duma resposta.